# htaccess: Mediafire.com like urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to come up with some mod_rewrite to translate `http://example.com/?7gudznrxdnu` into `http://example.com/view.php?id=7gudznrxdnu`

But any other page will function properly such as `http://example.com/contact` and so on.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, I'd be happy if you accepted my answer! :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}     ^[a-z0-9]+$
RewriteRule   ^$                  view.php?id=%{QUERY_STRING}    [L]
```

If you want the rewrite to be shown in the browser's address field, you'll have to replace `[L]` with `[L,R=301]`.

**Explanation:** The query-string (what's following the question mark) is not part of the URL that RewriteRule sees in its matching-pattern, therefore you can't check for question mark there. In my solution, I run the rule if and only if (`RewriteCond`) the query string consists solely of `a-z` and/or `0-9`, and my rule only rewrites URLs ending with a slash (except for the query string). I redirect this to `view.php?id=`, and then append the query string to that.

**Edit:** Tested on my Apache-server, and I haven't found any bugs (yet).

Answer (score 1):

You should try (in your .htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\?([^/\.]+)?$ view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This will redirect `/?asdf123` to `/index.php?asdf123`, if index.php exists.